# Why does my method return the wrong value?

Tags: java, return

Even though my method *operationsNeeded* prints the correct value for my return-int "count1", the very next line it returns something else to my main method. I did not include the rest of my code, if needed I'd gladly provide it. 
For example if *operationsNeeded* is executed 4 times, *count1* is on 4 which is printed out as well. But for reasons unknown to me the System.out.println("check: " +count1); Statement is executed 4 times like this:
**check: 4

check: 4

check: 3

check: 2**
I would expect my program to execute this only once and then continue to the return statement.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int testcases = sc.nextInt();
    int count =0;
    while (count<testcases){
        int numberOfColleagues = sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();
        String startPieces = sc.nextLine();

        int[] listOfcolleagues = listOfColleagues(numberOfColleagues, startPieces);

        int count2 = operationsNeeded(listOfcolleagues, 1);
        count++;
        System.out.println(count2);
    }

}

 public static int operationsNeeded (int[] listOfColleagues, int count1){
    //remove duplicates first
    ArrayList<Integer> relevantList=removeDuplicatesAndSort(listOfColleagues);
    System.out.println("relevantlist" + relevantList);
    //check for smallestdelta & index
    int [] deltaAndIndex = smallestDeltaHigherIndex(relevantList);
    int delta = deltaAndIndex[0];
    int index = deltaAndIndex[1];

    if (delta==1){
        for (int i=0;i<relevantList.size();i++){
            if (i!=index){
                relevantList.set(i,relevantList.get(i)+1);
            }

        }
    }
    if (delta>1 && delta<5){
        for (int i=0;i<relevantList.size();i++){
            if (i!=index){
                relevantList.set(i,relevantList.get(i)+2);
            }
        }
    }
    if (delta>4){
        for (int i=0;i<relevantList.size();i++){
            if (i!=index){
                relevantList.set(i,relevantList.get(i)+5);
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println(count1);
    int[] updatedList = new int[relevantList.size()];
    for (int i=0; i<relevantList.size();i++){
        updatedList[i]=relevantList.get(i);
    }
    if (!isAllTheSame(relevantList)) {
        count1 +=1;
        operationsNeeded(updatedList,count1);
    }

        System.out.println("check: " + count1);

 return count1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method is recursive. The `"check: "` line is printed on each level of that recursion, with the value that it currently has on that level. It first prints the "inner-most" value (4), than that of the level above (also 4), and finally hte value in the top-level, which is 2 after being incremented in the `if` above. And the value it `returns` is always the value from to top-level.

If you want to print it only once, you could print it on the inner-most level only, using `else`. However, that will still `return` the value from the top-level iteration; instead, keep track of the value returned from the recirsive call and update `count1` accordingly.

```
if (! isAllTheSame(relevantList)) {
    // we have to go deeper!
    count1 = operationsNeeded(updatedList, count1 + 1);
} else {
    // phew, finally done
    System.out.println("check: " + count1);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. 
I edited my code:  

`if (!isAllTheSame(relevantList)) {
            count1++;
            count1=operationsNeeded(updatedList,count1);
        }
        
     return count1;
    }`
  
Now it is working flawlessly! 
I thought since I called the *operationsNeeded* function before the return statement, that I would not reach the return statement until my if condition would be true. 
Would you mind to point out the mistake in my thinking?

Comment: @Louis Well, it still reaches the end of the calling function once the recursive call has finished. In that way, recursive invocations are in no way different than other method invocations.